# Cannot assign value to text

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to assign a value to text but it will not change from nil.

```
self.entryValue.text = @"1";
```

This should make entryValue display 1 but it is always nil. Any suggestions as to why?

Comment: Are you sure you assigned a value to `self.entryValue`? Is that a text field or label?

Comment: it is a text field

Comment: Apparently you never assigned a text field to `entryValue`.

Comment: textField.text is never nil even it doesn't have any string. Check outlet connection of entryValue. entryValue textfield outlet isn't connected properly and entryValue is nil

Comment: Check to see if you declared entryValue as a TextField with an IBOutlet keyword.  Check that you created a property, also with an IBOutlet keyword using the exact same name.  Check that you have an @initialize statement for entryValue at the top of your Class' .m implementation.  Open Interface Builder/Storyboard, and highlight The Owner of that screen which should be pointing to the ViewController of the scene you are working with.  Click on Outlets to see if the IBOutlet entryValue is connected to the TextField laid out on the screen.  If you have all that, it should work.

Comment: I think the problem was a threading issue. I was trying to assign the value using during a soap request response. What i did was just assign the incoming value to a dictionary and then at the end of the response, i called another method that assigned all of the values. It fixed my issue.